# Error message when trying to add extra geoim_point layer to ggplot lineplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a line graph using the following code:

```
    ggplot(out2, aes(factor(out2$term, levels=unique(as.character(out2$term)) ),estimate, group = 1)) +
        geom_line(aes(group = 1), size = 1.2) + 
        mytheme2 + 
        geom_point(shape = 21, colour = "black", fill = "white", size = 5, stroke = 2) + 
        scale_shape(solid = FALSE) + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1, size = 15, family = "serif")) + 
        scale_x_discrete(labels = labels1) + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
        geom_ribbon(data=out2,aes(ymin=conf.low,ymax=conf.high),alpha=0.1)
```

Which gives me this graph:

[image]

However, based on a variable in the data frame called `p.val` I would like to add one asterisk if the value of p.val is less then .05, and two asterisks if the value is less than .001.

I tried to add a line at the bottom of the code to achieve this:

```
    ggplot(out2, aes(factor(out2$term, levels=unique(as.character(out2$term)) ),estimate, group = 1)) +
        geom_line(aes(group = 1), size = 1.2) + 
        mytheme2 + 
        geom_point(shape = 21, colour = "black", fill = "white", size = 5, stroke = 2) + 
        scale_shape(solid = FALSE) + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1, size = 15, family = "serif")) + 
        scale_x_discrete(labels = labels1) + 
        #labs(y= "Standardized regression coefficient", x = "TAT threshold (Lux) minutes") + 
        #labs(title = "Sensitivity Analyses showing standardized regression coefficients for models with a range of \nTAT Light Thresholds (lux), Sleep Quality, Activity Level and BMI predicting T1 Hyperactivity.") + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
        geom_ribbon(data=out2,aes(ymin=conf.low,ymax=conf.high),alpha=0.1) +
        geom_point(data=out2[out2$p.value > 0.05,], color="red", size=3)
```

However, this gives me the error message:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x, y, group
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a data frame to the last `geom_point()` layer that is a smaller subset of the original `out2` and `ggplot` doesn't know how to distribute this shortened data across the original larger data, thus that warning.

It might be easier if you built a column in your data frame for the significance label first and then used `geom_text()` to layer it on instead of `geom_point()`.

```
out2$signif_label <- ifelse(out2$p.value < .05, "*", "")
out2$signif_label <- ifelse(out2$p.value < .001, "**", out2$signif_label)
```

then add this instead of the last `geom_point()`

```
geom_text(aes(label = signif_label), color = "red", size = 3)
```

If you assign `data` in the initial `ggplot(data = ,...)` call then all subsequent layers will try to inherit the same data, so we don't need to assign it again, unless it's different.